# multithreaded socket client conflict

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Is it possible to communicate with a TCP socket server on a single port via multiple threads either sharing a common socket or using independent sockets, without locking mechanisms or other cross-thread communication techniques?

**My specific problem:**

I am a beginner in python socket programming and trying to write a library to interface with a networked home automation device (GlobalCache GC100)

I need to both listen constantly for sensor state change events from this hardware via TCP as well as have the capability to send set_state commands (trip relays) at user initiated times, without significant delay.

I have a `while True:`loop which executes `socket.recv()` to pickup state change events. Most often this times out (`socket.settimeout(10)`) and continues to the next loop iteration until state change data is pushed by the device.

Now on top of this I need the user to be able to send set_state commands, and I don't want the user to need to wait until the socket.recv() times out and inject the communication between recv() loop iterations. So I opted to split the tcp listening loop into a separate thread using it's own socket (but pointed at the same host & port).

The problem is that the socket in the set_state thread seems to kill the socket in the listening thread and vice versa. It seems only the most recently created/connected socket is actually functional.

Am I trying to do something that is impossible with socket programming, or is this possibly just a limitation with the socket server implementation on my device (GC-100)?

The only solution to this I can see so far is to keep all socket communication in one thread, using a common socket, implement a communication queue, and keep the timeout duration to a very small value for the tcp-listening portion, so that set_state commands have to wait a minimal amount of time in the queue. But this seems less than ideal and somewhat fragile.

**EDIT:**

> It is the socket pair (the 4-tuple consisting of the client IP
>   address, client port number, server IP address, and server port
>   number) that specifies the two endpoints that uniquely identifies each
>   TCP connection in an internet. (TCP-IP Illustrated Volume 1, W.
>   Richard Stevens)

I figured perhaps I need to force a difference in the source port used by the multiple sockets in different threads. I tried `socket.bind(hostname, source_port)` but kept getting errors that the address was already in use, for all combinations of hostname&sourceport that seemed reasonable.

Comment: A single TCP socket is perfectly capable of sending/receiving data simultaneously.

Comment: @bnaecker I realized my description wasn't particularly good at illustrating the specific problem so I've edited it. My problem is related to communicating to one host&port on different threads simultaneously, whether through one or multiple sockets.

Comment: How does the user send the commands to the device? If it's through something like a text/command-line interface, you can use IO multiplexing to handle everything on a single socket. Look at the `select` or `selectors` modules, with which you would wait indefinitely until the user puts in a command or the device sends a state update.

Comment: Also, the `socket.bind()` call is only used in a server which will *accept* incoming connections. It sounds like you have two client sockets. Each of those only needs to call `connect()` to make a connection to the device.

Comment: @bnaecker This is for a library, for example, currently I do: 

`gc100 = GC100('192.168.1.100', 4998)`
`gc100.start_listener(callback_fn_for_statechg_event)`
`gc100.setstate(relay_id=1, state=0)`

Comment: A callback approach seems odd. Won't the calls to `setstate()` depend on the data sent from the device? Does the `setstate()` method check some aspect of the device's state, which may be modified by the callback? Also, it's starting to sound like a limitation of the device that it can only handle a single client. Is there any documentation on it that indicates how many clients it supports?

Comment: @bnaecker setstate is actually controlling relays whereas start_listener is providing state changes of digital inputs (not relays). For example doorbell is pressed, state change event is fired, then downstream automation calls setstate for the door chime relay. GC100 does not fire events for changed state of relays. And yes I confirmed (through experimentation, it's not documented) that only 1 client is supported so that I suppose means multiplexing is necessary. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Though not mentioned in their API docs I believe this is a limitation of the GC-100 server implementation. There are a plethora of examples about how to implement a tcp server which can support multiple simultaneous connections from multiple hosts.  Yet I configured two different hosts to connect to the unit and the device only allows a connection to one host at a time.

Thus it seems the only solution for me is to use a single socket, and to multiplex all reading and writing.

http://wiki.linuxmce.org/index.php/GlobalCache_GC-100#Implementation_details

> The gc100 software architecture uses two threads to communicate with
>   the gc100 regarding relays, IR transmitters and sensors, one for
>   sending messages (SocketThread) and one for receiving (EventThread).
>   The reason for this is that the gc100 protocol isn't completely a
>   request-reply protocol, even if it seems like that at first. The gc100
>   can initiate a transmission when a sensor is tripped, enough to break
>   the request-reply paradigm. The program was designed to treat the
>   communication as asynchronous. Messages are sent to the device without
>   expecting a reply, and the replies are treated as independent events
>   and state change reports, without linking a request to a reply in the
>   program logic (except for the initialization phase).